# JQUERY load -> "refresh" load the same javascript twice or higher

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i have a problem.

I use our admin control panel with dynamic loaded JQUERY.load();

But now when i want to refresh the page and this worked loaded 2 times the same javascript or higher.

**This will be loaded once on the start of our index.php**

```
    waitStatus = 1;
$('#a_set').load('content/ajax_admin.php',function(){
    waitStatus = 0;
});
```

**And this is the refresh code**

```
    $("#adm_refresh_c").click(function(){
    if(waitStatus == 0){
        waitStatus = 1;
        $('#a_set').fadeOut();
        $('#a_set').load('content/ajax_admin.php',function(){waitStatus=0;$('#a_set').fadeIn();});
    }
});
```

Its loading the same script 2 times or higher ( when i click **#adm_refresh_c** its load the content and by every loading its insert the same script ( when i click 10x refresh its loading 10x the javascript ).

Hope you understand it and can help me :)

Im allready try it with **.php?load=first** and only load it once this is working but not the best way i think.

Best whishes